# $(".class").val() is returning undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, getelementbyid

I'm hooking into the Trello API and creating a  with the Lists from a Board. I'm then attempting to list all the Cards from each List. When getting the ListID from the  value attribute, it's returning "undefined". Why is this?

I'm printing it out with `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $(".board").val();`

```
//HTML
<label>Choose from a List of Boards</label>
<div id="output"></div>

<label>Display Cards Below for Board Selected</label>
<div id="outputCards"></div>

<p id="demo"></p>

//Javascript
    var $boards = $("<select>")
            .attr("id", "boards")
        .text("Loading Boards...")
        .appendTo("#output");

    Trello.get("/boards/BOARD_ID/lists", function(boards) {
        $boards.empty();
        $.each(boards, function(ix, board) {
            $("<option>")
            .attr({href: board.url, target: "trello", value : board.id, name : board.id, id : board.id})
            .addClass("board")
            .text(board.name)
            .appendTo($boards);
        });  
    });


    var $cards = $("<div>")
        .text("Loading Cards...")
        .appendTo("#outputCards")
        .appendTo("#demo");

    // This is where I'm trying to return the value
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $(".board").val();

    var resource = "lists/LIST_ID/cards";
    Trello.get(resource, function(cards) {
        $cards.empty();
        $.each(cards, function(ix, card) {
            $("<a>")
            .attr({href: card.url, target: "trello"})
            .addClass("card")
            .text(card.name)
            .appendTo($cards);
        });  
    });
```

The HTML is outputting like this:

```
<label>Choose from a List of Boards</label>
    <div id="output">
        <select id="boards">
            <option target="trello" value="LIST_ID" name="LIST_ID" id="LIST_ID" class="board">
                List One
            </option>
            ...
        </select>
    </div>

<label>Display Cards Below for Board Selected</label>
<div id="outputCards"></div>

<p id="demo">undefined</p>
```

Comment: I don't know what `Trello` is, but I'm guessing `Trello.get()` does an asynchronous operation, so the `".board"` element will not yet have been created by the time your `$(".board").val()` line runs. And `.val()` will return `undefined` if `$(".board")` didn't match any elements. Any code that relies on the result of the `.get()` needs to be in that callback function, or in some other function called from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem here is that the `board` class is only being added to elements in the `Trello.get` callback.

As this code is executed asynchronously, it's likely that you are executing `$(".board").val()` before the code in the callback has been executed, meaning `$(".board") returned no elements.

I would consider something like this

```
Trello.get("/boards/BOARD_ID/lists", function(boards) {
        $boards.empty();
        $.each(boards, function(ix, board) {
            $("<option>")
            .attr({href: board.url, target: "trello", value : board.id, name : board.id, id : board.id})
            .addClass("board")
            .text(board.name)
            .appendTo($boards);
        });  
        // This is where I'm trying to return the value

        $('#board').change(function () {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $(".board:selected").val();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! But... now it's pulling in the ID for the first list (that loads by default), but doesn't update when I choose a new option from the <select>. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @user994585 I've updated the code with a fix (haven't tested it but I think it should work). You bind the `change` function to the `select` so that when the selected option changes, it updates the `demo` element with the selected value.